# symfony2 loginAction different render

Tags: symfony, view, authentication, render

I would like to know how to show the user a different page when he is logged in after filling the access form. I suposse I have to do it in my loginAction, but I don't know how.

My loginAction is the following:

> ```
> public function loginAction()
> {
>     $request = $this->getRequest();
>     $session = $request->getSession();
>
>     $error = $request->attributes->get(
>         SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR,
>         $session->get(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR)
>     );
>     return $this->render('UsuarioBundle:Default:login.html.twig', array(
>                              'last_user' => $session->get(SecurityContext::LAST_USERNAME),
>                              'error' => $error
>                              )); 
> }
> ```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `security.context` service for check is user authenticated fully and if so, render other template:

```
public function loginAction()
{
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    $session = $request->getSession();

    $error = $request->attributes->get(
        SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR,
        $session->get(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR)
    );

    if ($this->get('security.context')->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY') === TRUE) {
        return $this->render('UsuarioBundle:Default:logined.html.twig'); // render other template for fully authenticated users
    }

    return $this->render('UsuarioBundle:Default:login.html.twig', array(
                             'last_user' => $session->get(SecurityContext::LAST_USERNAME),
                             'error' => $error
                             )); 
}
```